# relation between unity on ubuntu and unity game engine?

Tags: ubuntu, unity

I am just curious to know if there is any kind of relation between Unity(the latest shell interface for gnome in ubuntu) and the Unity game engine, apart from having the same name ?

I saw my friends developing gesture recognition based software using Unity game engine and I use Ubuntu 12.04(uses unity interface) for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unity game engine and the Unity user interface are two different projects with the same name. 
You can explore the projects of the Unity user interface here: [Unity Project Website](http://unity.ubuntu.com/projects/)

Comment: thanks 4 clarification :) earlier when i heard the name then I thought there must be some relation..